# Special characters at the beginning of message after decryption

Tags: java, encryption

I'm encrypting a JSON message and sending it to the user. When they decrypt it, some of the messages show special characters at the beginning of the messages.

When i tried to decrypt from my side it's working fine. If they are decrypting it it shows special characters, but only for some messages as some are decrypting just fine.

Below is the Java code I am using to encrypt the messages and also adding code they are using to decrypt in .NET. Please help me understand this situation and why it's happening.

JAVA CODE(Encryption):

```
package com.kcs.mule.encryption;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncryption implements Callable {

    private static final String password = "fvtQhQcKZVWMCXRLbqmRgfEBXYWshTEP";
    private static int pswdIterations = 65536;
    private static int keySize = 256;
    private static byte[] ivBytes;

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        String plainText = eventContext.getMessageAsString();

        byte[] saltBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, pswdIterations, keySize);

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // encrypt the message
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        ivBytes = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] encryptedOutput = new byte[ivBytes.length+encryptedTextBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, encryptedOutput, 0, ivBytes.length);
System.arraycopy(encryptedTextBytes,0,encryptedOutput,ivBytes.length,encryptedTextBytes.length);
        return encryptedOutput;
    }

}
```

DOT Net Code(Decryption code):

```
byte[] saltBytes = key;
                PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key, saltBytes, 65536);
                var keyHash = keySpec.GetBytes(32);

                using (Aes aesCrypto = Aes.Create())
                {
                    //set the BlockSize and the KeySize before you set the Key and the IV
                    //to avoid padding exceptions.
                    aesCrypto.BlockSize = 128;
                    aesCrypto.KeySize = 256; // AES256
                    aesCrypto.Key = keyHash;
                    byte[] cipherTextCombined = request.MessageBytes;
                    byte[] IV = new byte[aesCrypto.BlockSize / 8];
                    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipherTextCombined.Length - IV.Length];

                    Array.Copy(cipherTextCombined, IV, IV.Length);
                    Array.Copy(cipherTextCombined, IV.Length, cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

                    aesCrypto.IV = IV; //Initialization vector
                    aesCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; //Cipher Block Chaining mode
                    aesCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                    // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesCrypto.CreateDecryptor(aesCrypto.Key, aesCrypto.IV);

                    // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    {
                        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
                            {
                                // Read the decrypted bytes from stream to string.
                                response.MessageText = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Actual result:

> ����wߞ*�/�r5le": {
>       "System": "KCS",
>       "Train": {
>         "TrainNumber": "36181542",
>         "TrainID": "G-CDMY -26",

Expected Result:

> TrainSchedule: {
>       "System": "KCS",
>       "Train": {
>         "TrainNumber": "36181542",
>         "TrainID": "G-CDMY -26",

Comment: Sounds like the problem is on their end, not yours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show how the message gets encrypted and decrypted in an incorrect way.

Comment: _One block_ of garbage (16 bytes for AES) is often caused by mishandling the IV for CBC (or less often CFB), but `Train Schedu` is 11 characters which is not normally 16 bytes unless you are using non-ASCII characters (such as Cyrillic) or invisible characters (such as BOM, BIDI, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible You are not encrypting the string "TrainSchedule" but they are decrypting TrainSchedule along with the payload.

Either encrypt the header or tell them to separate the payload from the header before decrypting it and concatenate it after.

Or, they are only decrypting the payload and ignoring the header. Without looking at their code it's impossible to know.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer Chi-Young

Comment: Hi Chi-Young, I am attaching the decryption code they are using and please help where they are missing in this